# Repetition of the program?

Tags: java, loops, repeat

I want to loop my program to repeat if the user inputs y the program will repeat over and over again ,but if the user finally inputs n the program will stop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseIt {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    String name;
    System.out.println("Input Name");
    name = sc.nextLine();

    StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(name);


    System.out.println("NAME: "+name+"\n");

    System.out.println("REVERSE:" +rev.reverse()+"\n");

    System.out.println("Would you like to do it again?(Y/N)\n");

    char repeat;

    repeat = sc.next().charAt(0);


    if(repeat == 'n'){
        System.out.println("Program  Stopped");
    }
        while(repeat == 'y'){
            System.out.println("Input Name");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("NAME: "+name+"\n");

            System.out.println("REVERSE:" +rev.reverse()+"\n");

            System.out.println("Would you like to do it again?(Y/N)\n");
        }

}
```

Comment: That's not an unreasonable goal. What have you tried?

Comment: You shouldn't miss your classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the code into a separate function, and call that function if the scanner returns a "y". For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
function();
}
public static void function(){
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

String name;
System.out.println("Input Name");
name = sc.nextLine();

StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(name);


System.out.println("NAME: "+name+"\n");

System.out.println("REVERSE:" +rev.reverse()+"\n");

System.out.println("Would you like to do it again?(Y/N)\n");

char repeat;

repeat = sc.next().charAt(0);


if(repeat == 'n'){
    System.out.println("Program  Stopped");
}
    if(repeat == 'y'){

function();

    }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: While in this example it's probably not a problem, recursive calls of this nature could have undesirable side effects ;)

Comment: True that, but this is just an example. OP can edit the code to stop this from happening

Comment: Oh yeah, in this case, it's minuscule. When you said to break it down into separate methods, I actually thought you might have a method for ask for a repeat (returning a `boolean`) and one more methods for the actual functionality all wrapped about in a loop, which I thought might be a good idea ;)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you could use a `do-while` loop...

```
do {
    //...
    System.out.println("Would you like to do it again?(Y/N)\n");
    String repeat = sc.next();
} while (repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

See [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details...

Answer (score 0):

Because, the question has to be asked once, it must be use do while statement to achieve what you are looking for.

Code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String name,finish;
    do{
    System.out.println("Input Name"); 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = sc.nextLine();
    StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(name);
    System.out.println("NAME: " + name + "\n");
    System.out.println("REVERSE:" + rev.reverse() + "\n");
    System.out.println("Would you like to do it again?(Y/N)\n");
    finish = sc.next();
    }while(finish.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

}
```